# Generate one set of Javadocs for two Android libraries in the same project

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc

I'm developing an Android SDK that is composed of two Android libraries: core and ui. Currently both have their `build.gradle` files where I have a task to build the javadocs for both.

What I would like to do is to have only one task in the parent directory `build.gradle` file so that only one set of javadocs is generated.

Any idea how to do this with Gradle?

Thanks!